# Find a linear transformation s.t the only invariant subspace is $0$ and itself

Tags: linear-algebra

In a finite dimensional vector space $V$, how to find a linear transformation s.t the only invariant subspace is $0$ and $V$.

---

I am considering the following transformation: suppose $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ are the basis, let $f(e_i)=e_{i+1},\ i=1,\cdots,n-1, f(e_n)=e_1$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Your considered transformation won't work.  The one-dimensional space spanned by $e_1+\dots +e_n$ is invariant.  As a hint: consider the "eigenvector" concept.

Answer (score 1):

Over which field are you working?

Every linear transformation on a complex vector space has an invariant subspace of dimension $1$.

Every linear transformation on a real vector space has an invariant subspace of dimension $1$ or $2$.

These facts follows from the fact that every linear transformation on a complex vector space has at least one eigenvector. (This fact is equivalent to the fundamental theorem of algebra).

So, the only possible examples can happen in a vector space of dimension $1$, in which every linear transformation works, or in a real vector space of dimension $2$, in which a rotation provides an example.

Comment: You'll have better luck over the rationals. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53091/589.